# Как указать TextView и EditText всегда быть внизу горизонтального LinearLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout

Внутри `LineaLayout` есть два элемента `TextView` и `EditText`. У кого из них высота будет больше не известно. `LinearLayout` в высоту занимает место по детям. Как указать детям, что бы они всегда были внизу общего `LinearLayout`? `TextView` занимает все свободное пространство по горизонтали. Вот как я пытаюсь это сделать. Если текст короткий, то он не опускается вниз Layout-a, а стоит по середине:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Короткий текст"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_text_max_weight"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="текст"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:ems="3"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Вид:

[image: вид]

Если текст длинный, то не опускается вниз `EditText`, а лезит выше:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Длинный текст Длинный текст Длинный текст Длинный текст Длинный текст Длинный текст Длинный текст"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_text_max_weight"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="текст"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:ems="3"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Вид 2:

[image: вид]

Пробовал `EditText` задавать layout_height = "match_parrent", но текст бывает занимает меньше места чем `TextView` и тогда он режется.

**UDP** Не весь код отобразился из-за разметки, поправил.
**UDP** Добавил картинки

Comment: Можете показать весь код разметки, и желательно скриншот, не совсем ясно из описания

Comment: @Werder Это и есть весь код. Добавил второй исход.

Comment: @Werder Добавил картинки

Comment: У LinearLayout пробовал менять атрибут android:orientation на vertical?

Comment: @Werder Мне нужна компоновка именно по горизонтали.

Comment: То есть тебе нужно чтобы при длинном тексте в TextView он не сдвигал EditText вправо?

Comment: @Werder EditText должен всегда находится справа, и оба элемента должны находится внизу Linealayout, а они не опускаются туда.

Comment: Не знаю правильно ли я тебя понял, но попробуй добавить атрибут android:layout_gravity="bottom" в LinearLayout

Comment: @Werder Это не оно, тогда просто весь LinearLayout летит вниз, а нужно только что бы внутренние элементы

Comment: Позвольте нам [продолжить обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25961/discussion-between-werder-and-iamtihonov).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот таким образом начертил, поместил обе вью в LinearLayout, по другому не получилось. Но вот интересно почему себя ведут так странно View внутри?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Текст"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom">
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_text_max_weight"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="текст"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:ems="3"/>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Как-то подобное делал, попробуй `RelativeLayout` и установи зависимость. Как делал я:

```
 <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="72dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10px"
            >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageMode"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:src="@drawable/home"
                android:layout_width="72dp"
                android:layout_height="72dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="16dp"
                android:paddingRight="16dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textprov"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:text="@string/name_mode_activity_add
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="76dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/TName"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="32dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/mode"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="72dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp" />

        </RelativeLayout>
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: извиняюсь, сразу не заметил, не весь код правильно разместился. Мне нужно что бы текст занимал все свободное пространство, которое ему оставил EditText в горизонтальной плоскости.